# Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, http-headers

From my iPhone app, I'm making a call to an ASP.NET web service. Below is my code

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://tbtesting/teambinder5/KEY9XXXXXX-cXXe-49XX2-acca-2XXXXXXXa9/Dashboard/DashboardWidgets.asmx/GetAnnouncement";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"*/*" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"en-us" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Language"];
[request setValue:@"gzip, deflate" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];
[request setValue:@"20" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
//[request setValue:@"3" forHTTPHeaderField:@"announceIntKey"];

NSError *error = nil;
NSURLResponse *response = [[NSURLResponse alloc] init];
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Following error occured: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}
else {
    NSString *returnValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"message: %@", returnValue);
}
```

Here is the header taken from fiddler.

```
POST http://tbtesting/teambinder5/KEY9XXXXXX-cXXe-49XX2-acca-2XXXXXXXa9/Dashboard/DashboardWidgets.asmx/GetAnnouncement HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-us
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 20

{"announceIntKey":3}
```

I'm getting the following error message.

**"Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027announceIntKey\u0027."**

After a little bit of searching here on SO I found out the cause for this error. It is because I'm not passing the `announceIntKey` and its value.

Although I know the reason, I'm kinda clueless on how to correct it. Since it looks like an object literal, you can't pass it like any other header value. All the example code I came across here on SO is for jQuery or some other language.

My question is how can I pass this value in Objective C?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're sending the content-type of application/json, so it would stand to reason that you need to pass the value as part of a `POST` containing a `JSON` body.

You will need to add that to the body of your request. You don't need to set the content-length as the NSMutableURLRequest will manage this for you.

```
NSString *body = "{\"announceIntKey\" : VALUE}";
[request setHTTPBody:[body dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
```

You'll need to replace `VALUE` with what actually goes into the `announceIntKey`.

Comment: Now it throws this error. **{"Message":"Exception of type \u0027System.ApplicationException\u0027 was thrown."**. I set the value like this `NSString *body = @"{\"announceIntKey\" : \"3\"}";` and like this also `NSString *body = @"{\"announceIntKey\" : 3}";`. Both times it returned the same error as above.

Comment: What WebService are you trying to call? Do you have the spec?

Comment: Its actually integrated with this web application running within my office. I don't have the spec at the moment.

Comment: I've just spotted the ASMX extension on the URL. WebServices in ASP.Net land typically use SOAP which is far more complicated, but not impossible to use.

Comment: Actually these web services were implemented long ago. By a separate team of devs. I cannot make any changes to them. Only now we're developing an iPhone client to that application using its already implemented web services. So I'm kinda stuck with http. :)

Comment: You can request the format of the SOAP by calling the .asmx with a ?WSDL parameter e.g. Dashboard/DashboardWidgets.asmx?WSDL. If this returns you a valid response it means you're dealing with SOAP.